# Start Task with static lambda

Tags: c#, performance, lambda, static, task

I´ve found this [article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/understanding-the-cost-of-csharp-delegates/)
and wanted to refactor some in my code to ensure there are only static lambda´s used. But I don't know how to make a lambda static if its a parameterless Func for another method.

E.g.: The definition of `public Task StartNew(Action action);` contains an Action which is an parameterless lambda. My call is: `Task.Factory.StartNew(() => parser.AnswerOnRequest(config, request));`
As the blogpost says this one generates non static classes which always generates a new object for every call, which I want (for learning purpose) to avoid.

Now I´ve written the following static method:

```
private static async void ExecuteAnswerOnRequest(TXRequestParser parser,
    AppMsgConfiguration config,
    VdvKaLogic.Implementation.SoapReqMsg01V03 request,
    Func<TXRequestParser, AppMsgConfiguration, VdvKaLogic.Implementation.SoapReqMsg01V03, Task> answerOnRequest) 
{
    await answerOnRequest(parser, config, request);
}
```

And call it like:

```
ExecuteAnswerOnRequest(parser, config, request,
    static async (parser, config, request) => await parser.AnswerOnRequest(config, request));
```

But somehow the `Task` is not parallel to the stack.

Now I want to know how to make the lambda static for `Task.Factory.StartNew` if the given lambda is parameterless.

Comment: Static has no relevance here

Comment: The cost of allocating an object to construct the delegate will be dwarfed by the work done by the thread management and whatever work is so time consuming it needs to be done asynchronously.  The odds that this is a problem are *very* low.  If you *actually* cared about reducing allocations you wouldn't be using `async/await` like this.

Comment: Why is your `ExecuteAnswerOnRequest` declared as `async void`? It does not seem like an [async event handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void)...